# Publishing Swift CLI to Homebrew with Makefile

Tags: swift, makefile, homebrew, publish

I have written a CLI in swift that I would like to distribute over homebrew. I have never published anything on homebrew before, so I followed [this tutorial](http://csl.cool/2023/10/27/ios-dev/upload-a-cli-tool-written-in-swift-to-homebrew/) pretty 1:1 I thought.

Here is my formulae:

```rb
class Compass < Formula
  desc "Command Line Interface for Sailor - A Frontend Web Framework in Swift"
  homepage "https://github.com/SailorWebFramework/Compass"
  url "https://github.com/SailorWebFramework/Compass", tag: "0.0.1"
  version "0.0.1"

  depends_on "xcode": [:build]

  def install
    system "make", "install",  "prefix=#{prefix}"
  end

  test do
    system "#{bin}compass", "help"
  end
end
```

and makefile:

```swift
prefix ?= /usr/local
bindir = $(prefix)/bin

# Command building targets.
build:
    swift build -c release --disable-sandbox

install: build
    install -d "$(bindir)"
    install ".build/release/Compass" "$(bindir)"

uninstall:
    $(RM) -rf "$(bindir)/Compass"

clean:
    $(RM) -rf .build

.PHONY: build install uninstall clean
```

When I run `brew install SailorWebFramework/formulae/Compass` I get:

```bash
==> Fetching sailorwebframework/formulae/compass
==> Downloading https://github.com/SailorWebFramework/Compass
```

...

```bash
==> make install prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/compass/0.0.1
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

I don't know why install is not being recognized. My best guess is that I don't have the pathing correct or maybe something is capital/lowercase when it shouldn't be? I've been staring at this for too long and I decided to throw in the towel. Another pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: should clarify that I can run make install locally (at the root of my project) and have it work as expected... the translation to the homebrew protocol is tripping me up.

Comment: Most likely the working directory you are invoking `make` in, is not the one where the `Makefile` lives.  make is not going to go searching the filesystem looking for makefiles: you have to either be in the right directory, or else use the `-f` option to tell make where to find the makefile or use the `-C` option to tell make to change its directory when starting.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I put the `Makefile` in the root of my project so I'm assuming somewhere in my Formulae the path is incorrect, but I am unfamiliar in this realm.

Looking at a swift example formulae [here](https://github.com/NSHipster/homebrew-formulae/blob/master/Formula/swift-syntax-highlight.rb), its corresponding project has the `Makefile` in the root as well [here](https://github.com/NSHipster/SwiftSyntaxHighlighter)...